# Uninstall ReSharper 4.5

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, installation, resharper, failed-installation

I have ReSharper 4.5 in Visual Studio 2008. Now I want to install ReSharper 5, but I can't do it before I uninstall ReSharper 4.5.

How can I uninstall ReSharper 4.5?

Comment: is there a simple upgrade feature? or do you need do install from scratch?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

> Control Panel
>   --> Add Remove Programs
>   --> JetBrains ReSharper 4.5
>   --> Uninstall

??

Comment: Damn I was looking for everything but JetBrains....why to confuse users? it should be straight forward named "Resharper" or "ReSharper by jetbrains"or something :D ReSharper is nice but too expensive for a beginner or hobbyst...

Comment: Agreed that it might be confusing as you'd typically look for ReSharper - not Jetbrains.. Not too expensive though. I'd gladly buy this on my own if me company didn't buy it for me. VS without R# is not the same..

Comment: Yes, it's ironic that the answer is so simple. But, being able to uninstall from Add Remove programs... that's insane. This is not a standalone program, this is a VS plugin. Why don't they offer some Uninstall plugin menu on Visual Studio. Or even the ReSharper guys themselves.

Comment: Now it's called "JetBrains Products in Visual Studio 20XX"

Comment: @Erandros to add insult to injury if your license server is (temporarily) down the plugin still sits there (you have to manually suspend it via Tools > Options) interfering with regular VS usage.  Or maybe I just don't remember how VS works without R# ;)

Comment: Unfortunately for VS 2017 it's no longer a standalone installation, so you will not find i there.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just install Resharper 5 directly?  It will override the Resharper 4.5

Answer (score 2):

After uninstalling Resharper from Control Panel, you might still see it in your visual studio.

So in order to remove it completely, follow these 2 steps :-

- Click on the Resharper 4.5 installer (exe file) and instead of "Install", select "Remove". It works just like how the Visual Studio installer works, same exe file is used to install/uninstall the software.
- Remove the Resharper files from "JetBrains" folder in AppData.

After doing this, visual studio will ask you to modify some settings. Restore it to default and then you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the Toolbox.

- Open toolbox
- Click on hexagon on a `Resharper Tools`
- `Configure Resharper Components`
- Choose `remove Resharper`
- Click next, accept and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but in VS 2017 you have to go to the Extensions panel and try to reinstall the program. When the standalone installer runs, it will give you an option to uninstall.  You cannot uninstall it directly from the Extensions panel, nor does it show up in `Control Panels > Programs and Features`.